# Logging out with Laravel 5.1

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1, logout, laravel-routing

I've been using Laravel 5.1 for 3 days and today I faced an obsticle. I'm trying to logout the authenticated user but I get:

> BadMethodCallException in Controller.php line 283: Method [getLogout]
>   does not exist.

In AuthController.php I put that:

```
public function getLogout() {
        parent::getLogout();
        Auth::logout();
    }
```

In routes.php

```
Route::get('auth/logout', 'Auth\AuthController@getLogout');
```

And this is the HTML in welcome.blade.php

```
<a href="auth/logout">Logout</a>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`getLogout` is a method on the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4b8b1cdc9332a7aa4afff5e5b3d7183e9d882550/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L111-L121), not on your controller's parent.

Remove your `getLogout` method entirely and everything should work as expected.

Comment: Oh, yes, it did work. Thanks a lot. I thought that I have to make a new child method of AuthenticatesUsers and to put Auth::logout(); in it because  in laravel's docs it says: To log users out of your application, you may use the logout method on the Auth facade. This will clear the authentication information in the user's session

Comment: @Alex - as you can see in the trait's `getLogout` method, [it calls `Auth::logout()` for you](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4b8b1cdc9332a7aa4afff5e5b3d7183e9d882550/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php#L118).

Comment: @JesephSilber Yeah I saw it. I really didn't think that Laravel's doing this for me. Thanks again!